# take screenshot and draw on it (android)

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, drawing, screenshot

I try to take screenshot of my screen and send it by intent to another activity.
In this another activity I have a class with custom view, which provides drawing.
I want to draw on screenshot from another activity. Take screenshot again and save on my sdcard.

So, in my **first activity**, where I take a screenshot and  send it to another activity :

```
  private void takeScreenshot() {

    try {
        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, CaptureSignature.class);
        intent.putExtra("SCREENSHOT", bitmap);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**activity with view**

```
 public class CaptureSignature extends AppCompatActivity {
    Signature mSignature;
    Paint paint;
    ImageView mContent;
    Button clear, save;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.capturesignature);

    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setEnabled(false);
    clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
    mContent = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mysignature);



    Bitmap bitmap = this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("SCREENSHOT");
    mContent.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    mSignature = new Signature(this, null,bitmap);

    save.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
    clear.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
}

Button.OnClickListener onButtonClick = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v == clear) {
            mSignature.clear();
        } else if (v == save) {
            mSignature.save();
        }
    }
};

public class Signature extends View {
    static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 10f;
    static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Path path = new Path();
    private Bitmap mBackground;

    float lastTouchX;
    float lastTouchY;
    final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

    public Signature(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, Bitmap background) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        this.mBackground = background;
    }

    public void clear() {
        path.reset();
        invalidate();
        save.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public void save() {
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mContent.getWidth(),
                mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        Drawable bgDrawable = mContent.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable != null)
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        mContent.draw(canvas);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        returnedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("byteArray", bs.toByteArray());
        setResult(1, intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBackground,0f,0f,null);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();
        save.setEnabled(true);

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                lastTouchX = eventX;
                lastTouchY = eventY;
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
                int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
                for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
                    float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                    float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                    path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
                }
                path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;
        }

        invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

        lastTouchX = eventX;
        lastTouchY = eventY;

        return true;
    }

    private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) {
        dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
        dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
    }
}
```

}

So, what problems I have: 
1) bitmap is too large for transfer by intent, so i can't to implement this
2)is it right solution on not at all?

maybe, anyone know, how to implement this task

Comment: Instead if sending bitmap to another activity, you can create screenshot in sdcard and send the filename alone, so that in next activity, screenshot can be read and processed.

Comment: @AnithaManikandan, yes, it`s work. 
maybe u know, how to paint by finger also on imageview .
As you see ,in my code  have custom view for drawing, but i can do this also on ViewGroup componenet like LinearLayout and other by adding mothod  addView(). But how to use ImageView, not viewgroup

Comment: If you are using Imageview, then you can have the drawing alone in it.  Say you need to have image and signature on top of it.  You can have photo in one imageView and have signature view on top of it.  Signature view will only have drawing with any background also.  Are you able to follow?